# Django Queryset How to add field using reverse foreign key

Tags: django

I have below two models,

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    nationality = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

class UserOption(DFModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Below is the viewset

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = apis_models.Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = apis_serializers.PersonSerializer
    permission_classes = [HasPermPage]
```

In above Person view I need to add useroption value associated with it for current logged in user.
UserOption model has User as well as Person.

```
{
  "id": 151,
  "name": "Emma Watson",
  "nationality": "USA",
  ”option”: “True”.   ##This is what needs to be added
}
```

This is really very complicated and I did not find any answer yet. Please advise.

Comment: Exactly when is `option` true, false, other value?

Comment: If option = monitor found in UserOption table.

Comment: If there is no entry then False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the queryset with an extra attribute:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = apis_models.Person
    serializer_class = apis_serializers.PersonSerializer
    permission_classes = [HasPermPage]

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            option=Exists(
                apis_models.UserOption.objects.filter(
                    user_id=self.request.user,
                    person_id=OuterRef('pk'),
                    option='monitor'
                )
            )
        )
```

In the serializer, you should add the `option` field:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    option = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'nationality', 'option')
```

Comment: I am getting this,
ImproperlyConfigured at /person/151/
Field name `option` is not valid for model `Person`.

Comment: @KalpeshTawde: did you add the `get_queryset` method? Note that if other viewsets use the same serializer, you probably should create a separate one for this `PersonViewSet`.

Comment: Hey it worked. I forgot to add
option = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
You are awesome man. Thank you very much!!